# Converting bytea to int[] in SQL in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgvector

My table in a PostgreSQL database stores a large number of integer arrays in the column called `vector`. Since all the numbers fit into the range from -128 to 127 and to save space, I use the `bytea` type. I need to use the dot product distance operator `<#>` provided by the `pgvector` extension, e.g.:

```sql
select id
from MyTable
order by vector<#>key
limit 10;
```

However, this operator does not support the `bytea` type. I want to convert my vectors to `int[]`, which can then be cast to the `vector` type supported by `pgvector`.

I think the general direction for converting `bytea` to `int[]` might be along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT string_to_array(encode(vector, 'escape'), '\\')::int[]
FROM MyTable;
```

How do I modify this to make the conversion work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join with `generate_series()` and use the `get_byte()` function:

```
WITH b(b) AS (VALUES (BYTEA '\x55FF1200DEADBEEF'))
SELECT array_agg(get_byte(b.b, g.i) - 128)
FROM b
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(0, length(b) - 1) AS g(i);

            array_agg             
══════════════════════════════════
 {-43,127,-110,-128,94,45,62,111}
(1 row)
```

This is going to be slow and inefficient, but that is to be expected if you try to save space at all costs.

I would recommend to use a `smallint[]`, which uses 2 bytes per number.

If you are running PostgreSQL v15 or later, you could also use an array of the internal data type `"char"`, which takes only one byte per element:

```
SELECT ARRAY[-43,127,-110,-128,94,45,62,111]::"char"[];

                 array                  
════════════════════════════════════════
 {"\\325",\x7F,"\\222","\\200",^,-,>,o}
(1 row)
```

To get an individual element, you use

```
SELECT (ARRAY[-43,127,-110,-128,94,45,62,111]::"char"[])[3]::integer;

 array 
═══════
  -110
(1 row)
```

A `"char"[]` uses one byte per element plus an overhead of 21 bytes per array (a `bytea` has an overhead of one or four bytes per value, depending on the size).

Comment: This gives each number in a separate row. I need a single value of type `int[]`, so as to be able to apply the distance operator as explained in the background part of the question. It also looks terribly slow...

Comment: I have fixed the answer to return an array. Yes, this is going to be slow and inefficient. That's typically the result of saving storage space.

Comment: Oh, couldn't I use `"char"[]` instead of `bytea` to begin with? But I can't find anything about this new type in the documentation. Could you please link to it? (BTW, why do you need the quotation marks?)

Comment: That's what I am suggesting: use `smallint[]` or `"char"[]` instead of `bytea`. This data type is not new at all. It is not really documented, and that's on purpose. There is something [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE). You need the double quotes to distinguish it from the standard data type `char`.

Comment: I found it documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html